# Converting ExpAverage(price[-0], 9) from thinkscript to pinescript

Tags: pine-script, thinkscript

I am trying to convert thinkscript to pinescript. I was hoping to convert the below into pinescript, but wasn't sure how to due to the price[-0]. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Code:
ExpAverage(price[-0], 9)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`price` with the historical operator `[-0]` (or `[0]` for that matter) is just the same as using `price`. The equivalent of ExpAverage() in pine is the `ta.ema()` function.

ie

`ema = ta.ema(close, 9)`

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta{dot}ema](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dema)